# using pushState with forward slashes

Tags: jquery, ajax, pushstate

I have the following push state:

```
 history.pushState(null, null, 'category/item');
```

whereas item is replaced dynamically.

Now this is used on click of my menu links.
The first time the pushState works nicely and rewrites the url.
But after that it doesn't work anymore.

Why does pushState have problems with forward slashes ?

Is there a way to use strings with slashes in them ?
Or do I have to escape them somehow ?

I'm going crazy with this issue

Thank for helping out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I was stupid enough to just not put a forward slash before the new url.
This caused the pushState to not route to the root nicely
With the slash it works nicely

Answer (score 0):

Careful with double slashes. It will break
http://example.com//doubleslash

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL